# RTL support for NavigationController with Back Button in iOS swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, back

I am developing the app which support Multiple language support. The content direction and content of the app changed with matching loaded language when i changed the language from an application. But, the Button in the navigation controller back button content is not changed and it's image is overlapped with the `Back` content.But its direction changed based on the loaded language. here i want to load `arabic` content of `Back` to that Back button. I didn't do anything programmatically. I just load the `arabic` content from Bundle.

[image]

Hope. i asked clearly my question. ask me if any doubt . I am very new to iOS Development.

Comment: Changing language within apps is not supported. You're going to run into many other issues and bugs since the app still believes it's running in a language that isn't the one you're overriding.

Adding a language switcher to your app is only going to make it more confusing; users expect their apps to follow the language that their device is set to.

Answer (score 0):

u can use that tutorial for [Internationalization](https://medium.com/if-let-swift-programming/working-with-localization-in-swift-4a87f0d393a4) but i see 2 ways: 
1. use localized strings:
add different  image to assets (like "bla_bla_us" - for US locale, "bla_bla_ar" - for arabic)
on init - set navigation item image programmatically

```
let image = UIImage(named: "bla-bla")
....
```

to *.strings file's add:

```
/*for US*/
"bla-bla" = "bla_bla_us"
```

to arabic *.strings add:

```
/*for arabic*/
"bla-bla" = "bla_bla_ar"
```

2. use separated storyboards(NOT localizations strings) for different locales